# How can I make the App Store remember my password?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, ios-appstore, password, apple-id

It seems that my iPod Touch (iOS 5.0.1) will keep asking for my AppleID password every time I try to install an application from App Store. It is really driving me insane.

I would be happy to add the password once at boot up instead of entering it each time.

I couldn't find a related option in Settings.

How do I change this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download "password pilot" in Cydia (the jailbreak app store) it will save your password so you wont have to keep entering it.

Answer (score 11):

You can't change this behavior.  Although, when you download a free app, you have to enter your password; if you download another free app immediately after, you won't have to re-enter your pass.  That's as close as you're going to get to a remember password feature on iOS 5.

This is something that was intentionally in place and now it's intentionally changed on iOS 6 to reduce the need to re-enter your password just for updates.

Comment: Yup. This additional security was added in response to kids downloading in-app upgrades within the 15-minute window and killing their parents' credit cards. Or something.

Comment: that hardly explains why the option can't be deactivated by enabling disabling restrictions

Comment: He asked for a way to change this behavior.  There isn't one.  No need for an explanation.

Comment: We can't answer for Apple's decisions here, all we can do is tell you the facts.